# Error "Token unknown - line 4, column 2; SET" creating trigger with variables

Tags: sql, triggers, firebird

I want to create a trigger, but I'm getting an error.

I have 2 tables STOK and STOK_HAREKET:

- STOK = (ID,URUN,FIYAT,MINIMUM,MAXIMUM)\
- STOK_HAREKET = (STOK_ID,FİYAT,GIRIS,CIKIS)\

I want to build a trigger to STOK_HAREKET. On insert and update, the GIRIS and CIKIS ın STOK_HAREKET table is collected and submitted
from the output and save this value to the MAXIMUM value ın the STOK table.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER T_STOK_BIU FOR STOK_HAREKET BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
AS
begin
 Set @gsum = ( SELECT SUM(GIRIS) FROM STOK_HAREKET WHERE STOK_ID = new.STOK_ID );
 Set @csum = ( SELECT SUM(CIKIS) FROM STOK_HAREKET WHERE STOK_ID = new.STOK_ID );
 Set @toplm = (@gsum-@csum)
 update STOK set MAKSIMUM =  @toplm where ID = new.STOK_ID
end
```

This code gives an error:

```
org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.sql.DBSQLException: SQL Error [335544634] [42000]: Dynamic SQL Error; SQL error code = -104; Token unknown - line 4, column 2; SET [SQLState:42000, ISC error code:335544634]
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCStatementImpl.executeStatement(JDBCStatementImpl.java:133)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.executeStatement(SQLQueryJob.java:578)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.lambda$1(SQLQueryJob.java:487)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.exec.DBExecUtils.tryExecuteRecover(DBExecUtils.java:173)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.executeSingleQuery(SQLQueryJob.java:494)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.extractData(SQLQueryJob.java:913)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.SQLEditor$QueryResultsContainer.readData(SQLEditor.java:3760)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetJobDataRead.lambda$0(ResultSetJobDataRead.java:123)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.exec.DBExecUtils.tryExecuteRecover(DBExecUtils.java:173)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetJobDataRead.run(ResultSetJobDataRead.java:121)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetViewer$ResultSetDataPumpJob.run(ResultSetViewer.java:5033)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.runtime.AbstractJob.run(AbstractJob.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Dynamic SQL Error; SQL error code = -104; Token unknown - line 4, column 2; SET [SQLState:42000, ISC error code:335544634]
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.FbExceptionBuilder$Type$1.createSQLException(FbExceptionBuilder.java:534)
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.FbExceptionBuilder.toFlatSQLException(FbExceptionBuilder.java:304)
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.AbstractWireOperations.readStatusVector(AbstractWireOperations.java:140)
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.AbstractWireOperations.processOperation(AbstractWireOperations.java:204)
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.AbstractWireOperations.readSingleResponse(AbstractWireOperations.java:171)
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.AbstractWireOperations.readResponse(AbstractWireOperations.java:155)
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.AbstractWireOperations.readGenericResponse(AbstractWireOperations.java:257)
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.AbstractFbWireDatabase.readGenericResponse(AbstractFbWireDatabase.java:201)
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.version11.V11Statement.prepare(V11Statement.java:89)
    at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBStatement.prepareFixedStatement(FBStatement.java:881)
    at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBStatement.internalExecute(FBStatement.java:868)
    at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBStatement.executeImpl(FBStatement.java:496)
    at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBStatement.execute(FBStatement.java:482)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCStatementImpl.execute(JDBCStatementImpl.java:329)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCStatementImpl.lambda$0(JDBCStatementImpl.java:131)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.utils.SecurityManagerUtils.wrapDriverActions(SecurityManagerUtils.java:96)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCStatementImpl.executeStatement(JDBCStatementImpl.java:131)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBSQLExceptionInfo: Dynamic SQL Error
```

Comment: which dazabase are you using?

Comment: thanks for the answer datebase firebird

Comment: firdbird uses variables in a different way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59567596/assigning-variable-in-sql-editor-context-in-firebird

Comment: This is generally wrong database design. You must avoid usage of stored aggregates as much as possible and the way you are trying to implement them is the worst of all possible. You will not only have concurrency and performance problems, your data may end up totally wrong because of transaction isolation rules.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you use is not valid syntax for Firebird. I recommend you review the Firebird 4.0 Language Reference, chapter [Procedural SQL (PSQL) Statements](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-psql) for the correct syntax for Firebird.

Specifically, you need to explicitly [declare variables](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-psql-declare-variable) before use, and use [`select ... into ...`](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-dml-select-into) to assign values from a select.

However, there are more problems with your trigger:

- You execute two separate selects, which could have been one select
- You retrieve values using two selects, and then use those for an update. This can be done in one merge statement
- As user13964273 remarks in the comments, doing this is a bad idea because of transaction visibility and performance (or having to retry concurrent updates which conflict)

Taken at face value, your trigger could be rewritten to:

```sql
create trigger T_STOK_BIU for STOK_HAREKET before insert or update
as
begin
  merge into STOK
  using (
    select STOK_ID, sum(GIRIS) - sum(CIKIS) as toplm
    from STOK_HAREKET
    where STOK_ID = new.STOK_ID
    group by STOK_ID
  ) as src
  on STOK.STOK_ID = src.STOK_ID
  when matched then update set STOK.MAKSIMUM = src.toplm;
end
```

However, you should consider instead using a view to calculate this on the fly when needed. Or use a table which has a summarized aggregate row, and insert changes (delta rows) into the table through a trigger, and on a schedule recompute the summarized aggregate row and delete those delta rows. You can then - use a view to calculate the actual value when needed, while reducing performance concurrency issues.

Comment: the code you gave is giving an error please help error: SQL Error [335544634] [42000]: Dynamic SQL Error; SQL error code = -104; Token unknown - line 10, column 3; using [SQLState:42000, ISC error code:335544634]

Comment: @MustafaUlusan Sorry, I made a typo, the second `using` should have been `on`. I fixed it in my answer.

Comment: sorry still not working error : 
      SRC.STOK_ID
      At line 10, column 20

Comment: @MustafaUlusan Sorry, I typed it without running it against an actual server as you hadn't provided a starting point. Should be corrected now.

Comment: the trigger worked, so the sql accepted, it did not give an error, but my running program is not working right now, it does not make a new update to STOK_HAREKET, it gives an error

Comment: 'STOK.MAKSIMUM = src.toplm;' IN ITS PLACE  'STOK.MAKSIMUM = '4';' It saves as 4 I think the problem may be related here

Comment: @MustafaUlusan I suggest updating your question with a [mre] that reproduces the problem.